# How to create a Pojo from a xsd:any Object sent with soap?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I am setting up a SOAP Server for a larger Project.
I have received a wsdl File which only specifies a xsd:any Field and not which type of Objects I can receive.

To simplify my question I have changed a simple helloworld application i have found. It is giving the same error as the more complex server I am working on:
"1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions"

So here I created a simple wsdl file, showing a Person Object that has the Fields:
- firstname
- lastName
- any

any could be, f.e. an animal.

```xml
<xsd:element name="person">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:any/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
```

I let jaxb generate the classes.
Since the xsd:any Object could be an Animal I created the Animal class:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"name" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "animal")
public class Animal
{
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And I have added the Animal to the ObjectFactory:

```java
    @XmlElementDecl(name = "animal")
    public Animal createAnimal()
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
```

My Endpoint should log the class of the any Object:

```
@Endpoint
public class HelloWorldEndpoint
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldEndpoint.class);

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://codenotfound.com/types/helloworld", localPart = "person")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Greeting sayHello(@RequestPayload Person request)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Endpoint received person[firstName={},lastName={}]", request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName());

        LOGGER.info("Any Class = {} ", request.getAny().getClass());
        //do stuff
        return response
    }
}
```

Finally the soap message I am sending with soapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://codenotfound.com/types/helloworld">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hel:person>
         <hel:firstName>John</hel:firstName>
         <hel:lastName>Doe</hel:lastName>
         <animal>
            <name>Elefant</name>
         </animal>
      </hel:person>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```